# How to apply this style (see picture) to text?

Tags: fonts

How can I replicate the style applied to the word "TOSS" in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE...

Sorry, your question is not clear, anyhow, I can answer what I understood:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

  Upon receiving $(\textsc{Toss}, \mathit{sid}, m, \mathbb{F}$
\en{document}
```

Please correct me, if my understanding is wrong...

Comment: I'm thinking it is `\textsc{Toss}`, perhaps.  Also, `\mathbb`, not `\mathb`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Added your suggestion too, Thanks for point out this...

Comment: Thansk a lot. I confim that `$(\textsc{Toss}, \mathit{sid}, m, \mathbb{F})$` worked.

Comment: @Lorenzo Thanks, I've modified the answer per your confirmation... Thanks to `Steven` too....

Comment: @Lorenzo If this answer fully satisfies your need and answers the question, you should click the check mark to the left of the answer.  This will give Mady the reputation "credit" for the answer and it will show readers of your question which (if several) answers you found most suitable to your need.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Please accept my sincere thanks....